# using pydantic causes stdlib dataclass frozen+slots behavior to change (read-only attribute error). why?

Tags: python, pydantic

Here is a minimal example of my dataclass usage:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(slots=True, frozen=True)
class MyStdLibDataclass:
    x : int = 0

d1 = MyStdLibDataclass(x=100)
assert d1.x == 100
```

The above code works. However, if I add the following code to the same file:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    y : MyStdLibDataclass|None = None

d2 = MyStdLibDataclass(x=101) # error here
assert d2.x == 101
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ross\Desktop\dataclass_bug.py", line 15, in <module>
    d2 = MyStdLibDataclass(x=101)
  File "<string>", line 3, in __init__
AttributeError: 'MyStdLibDataclass' object attribute 'x' is read-only
```

What am I doing wrong?

It appears that there is some side effect of using a stdlib dataclass in a pydantic model. Does pydantic patch the stdlib dataclass implementation?

Python 3.10.7, pydantic 2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a bug. I'm told that it should be fixed in pydantic 2.0.4.

See my bug report here:
https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/6840